# Search Graph API type=page empty result

Tags: search, facebook-graph-api, types, graph

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=platform&type=page&access_token=AAAAAAITEghMBAHNliisCo3f5nCVjRPaEUE6uZCpsbzOZB9LjXXbHTR5puUMbs6ObW91epZCAZCnzlqD1jXvd6K7EqiG71D1s7IojKY5eEgZDZD

All searches with type=page are returning empty results
Any ideas? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the access token. This type of search doesn't require it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Weird, In the documentation the example call has the token.